# How to return different types from flatMapLatest in RxSwift?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm following the RxSwift Example [GitHub SignUp using Driver](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/tree/master/RxExample/RxExample/Examples/GitHubSignup/UsingDriver), and ended up with something similar.

I have a network request that performs authentication and returns a `Observable<AuthenticationResult>`, in such way that I have this:

```
public enum AuthenticationResult {
    case canceled
    case usernameEmpty
    case passwordEmpty
    case invalidCredentials
    case granted(AccessToken)
    case other(Error)
}

// Authentication result status
let authenticationResult: Driver<AuthenticationResult>

authenticationResult = input.loginTaps.withLatestFrom(usernameAndPassword)
    .flatMapLatest({ (username, password) -> SharedSequence<DriverSharingStrategy, AuthenticationResult> in
        return API.authenticate(username: username, password: password, applicationScope: .property).trackActivity(signingIn).asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: .canceled)
    })
    .flatMapLatest({ (result) -> SharedSequence<DriverSharingStrategy, AuthenticationResult> in

        switch result {

        case .granted(_):
            // The closure is expecting a return value here that I don't have!
            let portfoliosNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: PortfoliosTableViewController())
            wireframe.show(viewController: portfoliosNavigationController)

        default:

            return wireframe.promptFor(result.description, cancelAction: "OK", actions: [])
                .map({ (_) -> AuthenticationResult in
                    result
                }).asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: result)

        }

    })
```

Now, here's the **issue**:

My `flatMapLatest` expects a `SharedSequence<DriverSharingStrategy, AuthenticationResult>` and I don't always have that to return!

Inside the closure, I can return `SharedSequence<DriverSharingStrategy, AuthenticationResult>` **if authentication succeeds**, because my `wireframe.promptFor` returns an observable.

However, when **authentication fails**, I don't have an observable to return. My `wireframe.show` method doesn't return anything.

How can I handle this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: What do you get returned from `API.authenticate` when authentication fails?

Comment: I get a SharedSequence<DriverSharingStrategy, AuthenticationResult>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the switch case `.granted` was that the authentication was successful, you can simply return `Observable.empty()` or `Driver.empty()`.

### What does that do?

By returning an empty driver sequence in a `flatMap` operation, you mean to end the observable sequence. The stream will receive the `onCompleted` event, which you can comprehend as *the stream or operation was successful*.

Your following code would then be found in the `onCompleted` closure in the `drive()` method.

```
// Your observable stream / driver sequence
.drive(onCompleted: { [unowned wireframe] in

    let portfoliosNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: PortfoliosTableViewController())

    wireframe.show(viewController: portfoliosNavigationController)

}
```

That should work.

### The RxCocoa `Driver` unit

By using the [Driver unit](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/Traits.md), you're saying that you're expecting an observable sequence will have the following traits:

- Can't error out
- Observe on main scheduler
- Sharing side effects (shareReplayLatestWhileConnected)

This is commonly useful when performing UI related things (such as what you want to do which is displaying a navigation controller). If that is the case, continue using Drivers.

### But what if my stream might encounter errors?

If for some chance you need to return to an observable sequence so that you can error out (because you're going to perform an observable operation that may error, or because you want to throw an error to stop the operation), then you can use the `toObservable()` operation on the `Driver` instance.

Be careful though, because you lose the assertion that you will run on the main thread (which you need for showing view controllers).